# delete duplicates based on combined value of fields

Tags: sql, data-warehouse

I have a table with 3 key columns called services (service1, service2, service3) and other value columns. I want to delete all duplicate records from the table based on combination of 3 key fields (in any order). for e.g. records with key fields 'car,truck,bike' and 'bike,car,truck' are duplicate records inspite of position of the field values.
Note: Edited my answer for more detailed statement in the comments.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Sample data and desired results would help. The question is too vague for a sensible answer.

Comment: What database are you using?  Also, don't store CSV into your SQL tables.

Comment: Do you want to remove all such records, e.g. if there are three records sharing one set of services, should all three of them be removed? Or should one remain? And is there a column or a combination of columns, are suitable as keys?

Comment: Ok, so here is a little more detailed problem statement. I have data in teradata (but any SQL based solution would be helpful).
I have 3 key fields called service1, service2, service3 which includes rental details of all services customer can avail. So suppose there's 1 record with the values in database as Service1: Car, Service2: Truck, Service3: Bike
Another record has same key values but in different order like Service1: Bike, Service2: Car, Service3: Truck
Now I want to keep only 1 such record and delete all other duplicate records based on any order of key values.
Another record is

Comment: Sticky bit: Yes, these are 3 different columns and only 1 needs to be retained in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the table is poorly designed, so I would consider refactoring entirely.

But to deal with it as is (and to not use a cursor), I think the quickest way is to list out every possible permutation to find the duplicates, and then assign a row number.

Example:

There are 6 permutations of the numbers 1 2 3:

```
123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321
```

Same goes for your example of 'bike' 'car' 'truck':

```
'bike' 'car' 'truck', 'car' 'bike' 'truck', ... etc.
```

So we want to partition the data in your table into groups of duplicates (based on all the possible permutations), and assign a row number to each row in the partition.

### [Click here for a working example in SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c927e5/2)

Example table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE services
  (  service1 VARCHAR(10),
     service2 VARCHAR(10),
     service3 VARCHAR(10) 
  ); 

--these first three values duplicate each other. They should end up 
--partitioned together in our query
INSERT INTO services VALUES ('bike', 'car', 'truck');
INSERT INTO services VALUES ('truck', 'bike', 'car');
INSERT INTO services VALUES ('car', 'truck', 'bike');
--this fourth value should be in a partition on it's own
INSERT INTO services VALUES ('moped', 'car', 'truck');
```

Run this query to see the results of the partition. This is essentially saying create a partition for all rows where the three columns equal a different permutation of itself:

```
SELECT s.*,
       Row_number() over(PARTITION BY (SELECT DISTINCT 1
                                       FROM   services s1
                                       WHERE (    s1.service1 = s.service1
                                              AND s1.service2 = s.service3
                                              AND s1.service3 = s.service2)
                                          OR (    s1.service1 = s.service2
                                              AND s1.service2 = s.service1
                                              AND s1.service3 = s.service3)
                                          OR (    s1.service1 = s.service2
                                              AND s1.service2 = s.service3
                                              AND s1.service3 = s.service1)
                                          OR (    s1.service1 = s.service3
                                              AND s1.service2 = s.service1
                                              AND s1.service3 = s.service2)
                                          OR (    s1.service1 = s.service3
                                              AND s1.service2 = s.service2
                                              AND s1.service3 = s.service1) )
                       ORDER BY (null)) AS rownumber
FROM     services s;
```

Now that you have the results, you can see that you'll need to delete any row where the `rownumber` is greater than 1:

```
DELETE
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             Row_number() over(PARTITION BY (SELECT DISTINCT 1
                                             FROM   services s1
                                             WHERE (    s1.service1 = s.service1
                                                    AND s1.service2 = s.service3
                                                    AND s1.service3 = s.service2)
                                                OR (    s1.service1 = s.service2
                                                    AND s1.service2 = s.service1
                                                    AND s1.service3 = s.service3)
                                                OR (    s1.service1 = s.service2
                                                    AND s1.service2 = s.service3
                                                    AND s1.service3 = s.service1)
                                                OR (    s1.service1 = s.service3
                                                    AND s1.service2 = s.service1
                                                    AND s1.service3 = s.service2)
                                                OR (    s1.service1 = s.service3
                                                    AND s1.service2 = s.service2
                                                    AND s1.service3 = s.service1) )
                               ORDER BY (null)) AS rownumber
   FROM     services s )
WHERE rownumber > 1;
```

Side note: I wrote this for Oracle. I've never used Teradata, so they may have a different way of partioning. See http://www.bikinfo.com/HTML/TD/TD_vs_Oracle.html#_Toc_Qualify

Comment: Looks a little complicated. Can you briefly explain the steps, sorry not as good in SQL as I should be to understand this.

Comment: I rewrote the example differently and provided more explaination.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mallorie, that was really helful, will try over the weekend.